# AEM 6.3 using Filter, does not work

Tags: filter, aem

I want to catch all requests inside a filter in AEM 6.3. The filter is the following:

```
@Component(
        property = {
                "pattern=/.*",
                "service.ranking=" + TryFilter.SERVICE_RANKING
        }
)
public class TryFilter implements Filter {

    public static final int SERVICE_RANKING = 2147483647;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TryFilter.class);
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        LOG.debug("Begin Filter");
        LOG.debug("End Filter");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
```

The problem is the filter does not catch requests like http://localhost:4502/aem/start.html Especially requests that end in .html. Do you have any idea about what can be the problem? I checked the patternUrl for the filter, but for http://localhost:4502/crx/de/index.jsp it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sumarize, you should register your filter service as:

```
@Service
@Component(metatype = true,
    immediate = true,
    label = "An example filter for html requests.",
    description = "This filter will handle html requests. Actual logic performed inside doFilter method.")
@Properties({ 
    @Property(name = EngineConstants.SLING_FILTER_SCOPE, value = { EngineConstants.FILTER_SCOPE_REQUEST }, propertyPrivate = true),
    @Property(name = Constants.SERVICE_RANKING, intValue = TryFilter.SERVICE_RANKING, propertyPrivate = true),
    @Property(name = EngineConstants.SLING_FILTER_PATTERN,  value = "*.html", propertyPrivate = true)
    })
```

Beside I would recommend adding a log inside the `activate` method beside one inside `init`

```
/**
 * Handle OSGi activation.
 *
 * @param context osgi component context
 */
@Activate
protected void activate(final ComponentContext context) {
    if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
        TryFilter.LOG.info("activate " + getClass());
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

- Prior to AEM 6.3

Felix Filters were registered with only the `pattern` property, as in your example, which defined path pattern for which the filter responds to.

```
@Component(immediate=true)
@Property(
    name = "pattern",
    value = ".*"
)
@Service
public class TryFilter implements Filter { .. }
```

- Starting AEM 6.3

Felix Filters must provide the `osgi.http.whiteboard.filter.regex` and `osgi.http.whiteboard.context.select` properties to be properly registered.

```
@Component
@Properties({
        @Property( name = HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_FILTER_REGEX,
                value = "/"
        ),
        @Property( name = HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_CONTEXT_SELECT,
                value = ("(" + HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_CONTEXT_NAME + "=org.osgi.service.http)")
        )
})
@Service
public class TryFilter extends Filter { ... }
```

The following dependencies are required to be updated in order for the annotations to be processed properly.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>osgi.core</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>osgi.cmpn</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I need filter to handle all my requests ... even if it's sling request or not.. that's my problem..

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but are you sure about it? IMHO this could create a major bottle neck in your application, not to mention the risks of interfering with AEM OOTB behaviour

Comment: I am trying to add dinamically a javascript script and a link to a css file, in the head of every page. The idea is to have a sticky note on each page. So for 6.1 i used an normal servlet filter that is registered in the httpwhiteboard. this filter caught each request, either crx/de/index.js or /content/page.html(this is only an example) and the sticky note worked. Now when i migrated to 6.3 the filter does not catch anymore the /content/page.html requests. I dont know exactly why those request are not caught anymore and how to solve the problem.

Comment: I still think it suits better your case to only handle requests that come through the SlingRequestProcessor instead of registering a Felix filter. Still, if you want to achieve registering the Felix filter, I've updated my answer, please take a look

Comment: Thank you very much.. I have registered the filter, but still sling request are not caught in the felix filter, for example /content/page.html...

Comment: I wanted to use felix filter because i need the sticky note to be also on crx/de/index.jsp and system/console... and those ones are not sling requests. Is there another work around to catch all kind of requests? thx

Comment: My problem was solved adding an extra property to your suggestion

Comment: @Component
@Properties({
        @Property(name = HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_FILTER_REGEX,
                value = ".*"
        ),
        @Property(name = HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_CONTEXT_SELECT,
                value = ("(" + HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_CONTEXT_NAME + "=org.osgi.service.http)")
        ),
        @Property(name = "sling.filter.scope", value = "request"),
})

Comment: Perfect. Glad I could help, and thank you for posting the concluding annotation.

Comment: :) Seems @awd user deleted his answer and down-voted mine. What a nice attitude

Comment: [aem-acs-sample](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-samples/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/samples/filters/impl/legacy/SampleServletFilter.java) works in AEM 6.1 but in AEM 6.2 the sling engine is coming before filter. @DenisaCorbu did you test your change in AEM 6.2 or 6.3? Ideally Filter should come before Sling Engine